# generating random colored squares using opengl

Tags: opengl, random, colors

how would you generate random coloured square in open-gl? the output of the programme should look something like the pic

[image]

Comment: i was going through a tutorial online and it asked to try programme this but im not having any joy

Comment: user170705: talk us through how YOU think you might do this....

Comment: well ive mt black canvas drawn(640 by 480). I can draw a colored square using glvertex2f but im not sure how to set random colors or how to draw these squares in a pattern like above

Comment: If you can draw a square with specific red, green, and blue color values, then if you generate a random value for red, green, and blue, it will be a random color.  Do you know how to generate a random value?

Comment: no i dont. can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) or maybe the [Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister):

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, 0);
glColor3ub( rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255 );
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2i(0,0);
glVertex2i(1,0);
glVertex2i(1,1);
glVertex2i(0,1);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Modulus is pretty bad if you're looking for crypto-grade pseudo-random numbers but for this application it should work fine.

Comment: cheers man. i presume i can put this into a loop to try get the pattern in the image. thanks

Comment: Yep, that's the intent with the `xpos`/`ypos`.